# Выделение диапазона элементов из матрицы numpy

Tags: python-3.x, матрицы, numpy

Есть матрица образованная применением преобразования Фурье к wav-файлу
Есть ли возможность выбрать элементы матрицы, которые находятся между x и y с помощью внутренних функций numpy/python или придется перебирать все элементы?

Comment: возможно подойдёт `matrix[x1:x2]` (получает подмассив по индексам от x1 включительно до x2 невключительно)

Comment: приведите небольшой пример данных (5-7 строк) и то, что хотите получить на выходе. Например: `np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)`

Comment: Создав массив даже так, как вы предлагаете
Допусти x = 3, y = 5
На выходе нужно получить все элементы массива, находящиеся между x и y.
То есть x < a[i] < y, при этом массив на 9000 значений через for перебирать нет возможности